# How to Code on checkbox which is add in listview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview, checkbox

I found a solution how can you do this follow this code for code in on click event of check box which is in list box. hope this is full for you guys.

Comment: It's kind of tough to tell what you're asking.  Can you try to clarify?  Maybe give an example of what you want to do?  It sounds like you want to save somethingto a database whenever someone checks that "CheckBox1" ChecBox control.  Is that correct?  If so, what don't you understand about how to do that?

Comment: YES i want to save CheckBox1.Checked value in data base when i check the check box

Comment: Okay. Which part are you having trouble with - handling the OnCheckedChanged event, or the database transaction?  Or both?

Comment: Have a trouble with check box check when i check any check box in a list then i want to run a code for save data. i.e if check box is true then data will be save if check box is uncheck then i want to delete value which i was saved with check box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add checkbox in listview below:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="Check" 
runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

and have to code like this for work on it:
C#:

```
<script  runat="server">
    public void Check(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Some code here......
    }
</script>
```

VB:

```
<script  runat="server">
    Public Sub Check(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    //Some code here......
End Sub
</script>
```